# PHP & MySQL - Limiting an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to limit the array `mysql_fetch_assoc($query)`, and am unsure on how I would go about it.

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC');

while($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    //do something
}
```

Do you add a counter or something? How do you add this counter?
I'm really confused about `mysql_query` and `mysql_fetch_assoc`. Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your `ORDER BY id DESC`, add `LIMIT 100` (or whatever number you want). For the next 100 rows, use `LIMIT 100,100`, then `LIMIT 200,100` and so on.

Comment: Awesoooomm!!! Thanks for the extra bit about the range of the limit. That will help me a lot!!!!!

Comment: @Kolink Isn't it `LIMIT 101, 100` and `LIMIT 201, 100`?

Comment: Okay, havn't noticed well! :P

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the results directly in the SQL query. To get the top 100 records do

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `LIMIT`

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Haven't you seen phpMyAdmin always limiting to `30`?

Comment: lol, i don't really look at what phpMyAdmin does, just make it do stuff. But thanks for the advice. I'll take more notice of such things from now on!

Comment: And yeah, for the pagination, do as [Kolink](http://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/kolink) said. :)